# Pandas Dataframe find max value out of the next few rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a price column and a max value column:

```
PRICE          MAX

1.095806 <-    1.095806
1.046494 <-    1.046494
1.019099 <-    1.019099
1.002662       1.035535
1.019099       1.035535
1.008142       1.035535
1.035535 <-    1.035535
1.019099 <-    1.019099
0.986225 <-    0.986225     
0.964309       0.975267
0.953351       0.980745
0.964309       1.030057
0.964309       0.964309
0.975267 <-    1.068410
0.980745 <-    1.117722
1.030057 <-    1.145117
1.068410 <-    
1.117722 <-
1.145117 <-
1.139638
```

I want MAX to find the highest PRICE value of the next 5 rows.

I tried `df['MAX'] = df['PRICE'].rolling(5).max()` but it isn't right.

I believe I need to use shift(-5). Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use rolling with `4` and `shift` with `-3`:

```
df['MAX'] = df['PRICE'].rolling(4).max().shift(-3)
print (df)
       PRICE       MAX
0   1.095806  1.095806
1   1.046494  1.046494
2   1.019099  1.019099
3   1.002662  1.035535
4   1.019099  1.035535
5   1.008142  1.035535
6   1.035535  1.035535
7   1.019099  1.019099
8   0.986225  0.986225
9   0.964309  0.964309
10  0.953351  0.975267
11  0.964309  0.980745
12  0.964309  1.030057
13  0.975267  1.068410
14  0.980745  1.117722
15  1.030057  1.145117
16  1.068410  1.145117
17  1.117722       NaN
18  1.145117       NaN
19  1.139638       NaN
```

Or rolling with `5` and `shift` with `-4`:

```
df['MAX'] = df['PRICE'].rolling(5).max().shift(-4)
print (df)
       PRICE       MAX
0   1.095806  1.095806
1   1.046494  1.046494
2   1.019099  1.035535
3   1.002662  1.035535
4   1.019099  1.035535
5   1.008142  1.035535
6   1.035535  1.035535
7   1.019099  1.019099
8   0.986225  0.986225
9   0.964309  0.975267
10  0.953351  0.980745
11  0.964309  1.030057
12  0.964309  1.068410
13  0.975267  1.117722
14  0.980745  1.145117
15  1.030057  1.145117
16  1.068410       NaN
17  1.117722       NaN
18  1.145117       NaN
19  1.139638       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that when you say it isn't right because of the `nan` values.

You can set the `min_periods` value to overcome that

```
>>> df
   price
0      4
1      8
2     28
3      6
4     23
5     26
6     41
7     20
8     18
9      7
```

You can the find the max in the rolling window like this.

```py
>>> df.price.rolling(5, min_periods=1).max()
0     4.0
1     8.0
2    28.0
3    28.0
4    28.0
5    28.0
6    41.0
7    41.0
8    41.0
9    41.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```